# Validating different patterns

Tags: regex

I am trying to learn regular expressions to validate specific inputs. The inputs I am trying to validate consist of the following patterns:

A regular expression to match the following pattern of phone numbers that might include a `.` or `-` or space. My data looks like this:

```
num: 1234567890 name: jack
num: 123-456-7890 name: john
num: 123.456.7890 name: jeff
num: 123 456 7890 name: josh
num: (123) 456-7890 name: jacob
```

A regular expression to match a social security number that might include dashes or spaces following the 3rd and 5th digit.

```
ss: 111111111 name: jack
ss: 111-11-1111 name: john
ss: 111 11 1111 name: jeff
```

I have tried `\d{3}-?.?\d{3}-?.?\d{4}` for the phone numbers.

And tried `\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}` for the social security numbers.

Comment: `.` must be escaped in a regular expression. Except if you put it in a character class. For example, the character class that separates the digits can be `[.- ]`.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle: That's an invalid character class. Notice that the `-` has special meaning…

Comment: Why is it wrong? Look at smerny's answer. That is what (s)he used and it works.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle, it makes a difference if it is between characters or not. If it is not between it won't need to be escaped.

Comment: I understand now. `[ .-]` is interpreted as [` ` or `.` or `-`] whereas `[.- ]` is interpreted as [between `.` and ` `].

Comment: Now I understand what is meant by character class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the portion of the phone numbers you could use..

```
\(?\d{3}\)?[-. ]?\d{3}[-. ]?\d{4}
```

Regular expression:

```
\(            # match '('
  ?           # match between zero and one time
  \d{3}       # match a digit (0-9) (3 times)
\)            # match ')'
  ?           # match between zero and one time
  [-. ]       # match for '-', '.', or ' '
  ?           # match between zero and one time
   \d{3}      # match a digit (0-9) (3 times)
   [-. ]      # match for '-', '.', ' '
  ?           # match between zero and one time
   \d{4}      # match a digit (0-9) (4 times)
```

And for the social security numbers, something like..

```
\d{3}[- ]?\d{2}[- ]?\d{4}
```

Answer (score 1):

For phone number, try this:

```
\(?\d{3}\)?[ .-]?\d{3}[ .-]?\d{4}
```

`[ .-]?` is basically saying "one or zero" of space, hyphen, or dot.

For ssn:

```
\d{3}[ -]?\d{2}[ -]?\d{4}
```

`[ -]?` is basically saying "one or zero" of space or hyphen.

---

But honestly rather than care about format (which might frustrate user and you - trying to account for various formats), in most cases I'd rather just make sure they have the right amount of numbers. You could remove any non-numeric character and then check the length.

How this is done would depend on the language being used. In javascript, it could look as simple as:

```
if(phoneNumber.replace(/\D/g, "").length() === 10){ //valid }
```

Then you could format or use it however you want from that point. Here is a javascript example of that: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BArME/)... an example using a specific format: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BArME/2/)

Answer (score 0):

try this reg exp

```
(\(\+?\d+\) |\+?\d+)([ -.]?\d+)*
```

It looks like [it works](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%5C%28%5C%2b?%5Cd%2b%5C%29%20%7C%5C%2b?%5Cd%2b%29%28%5B%20-.%5D?%5Cd%2b%29%2a&input=num%3a%201234567890%20name%3a%20jack%0Anum%3a%20123-456-7890%20name%3a%20john%0Anum%3a%20123.456.7890%20name%3a%20jeff%0Anum%3a%20123%20456%207890%20name%3a%20josh%0Anum%3a%20%28123%29%20456-7890%20name%3a%20jacob) as required.